# try convert string to date row per row in pandas or similar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I need to join dataframes with dates in the format `'%Y%m%d'`. Some data is wrong or missing and when I put pandas with:

```
try: df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%Y%m%d')
except: pass
```

If 1 row is wrong, it fails to convert the whole column. I would like it to skip only the rows with error without converting.

I could solve this by lopping with datetime, but my question is, is there a better solution for this with pandas?

Comment: add `errors='ignore'` into your `pd.to_datetime` call. you can can read more from the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: @mitoRibo `errors='ignore'` will return the input Series without any change if an error is raised

Comment: I think that's what OP wants rather than NaT, but it will be easy for them to find which option they need

Comment: @mitoRibo what is was trying to say is that `errors='ignore'` is basically the same behaviour as the current OP's code. It doesn't skip the conversion of  the value with a wrong format, it ignores the full conversion if an error is found. It's a bit misleading, I have already fallen into the same trap.

Comment: @Rodalm thanks so much for patiently explaining. I tried a small example for myself and you're exactly right! I guess the reason is because you can't have non-dates in datetime64 column, so it gives up on the whole column? thanks again

Comment: @mitoRibo No problem, I'm always glad to help! The motivation behind this implementation choice should be related to that, but in my humble opinion, the behaviour of just ignoring the values with the wrong format would be more useful in most scenarios ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `errors = 'coerce'` to `pd.to_datetime` to convert the values with wrong date format to NaT. Then you can use `Series.fillna` to fill those NaT with the input values.

```
df['data'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
      .fillna(df['data'])
)
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#:%7E:text=errors%7B%E2%80%98ignore%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98raise,return%20the%20input.)

> **errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’**
>
> - If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
> - If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
> - If 'ignore', then invalid parsing will return the input.